# js - How to change one key's value based on another key's value in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration

I have an array of objects like this:

```
var chartData = [{count: 0, idTag: "24"}
                 {count: 0, idTag: "25"}
                 {count: 0, idTag: "26"}]
```

My code does some work and generates a number (`totalValue`). If `totalValue` matches the `idTag`, its `count` gets increased by one:

```
for (i=0; i<timesFlipped; i++) {
    totalValue = runTrial();
    for (j=0; j<chartData.length; j++) {
        if (chartData[j].idTag === totalValue) {
            chartData[j].count += 1;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is a simple example, but `chartData` could hold a few dozen objects, and `timesFlipped` can be hundreds of thousands of iterations.

Is this the best way to change the `count` value based on matching the `idTag` value? Is there a way to just find the index of the array with the correct `idTag` value without iterating over the whole array of objects?

Here's the page I'm working on if you want more context: http://blue.butler.edu/~aazman/coupling/

---

**Update:**

Thanks for all the suggestions. I kinda formed my own solution based on what I saw. A bit more background about the project which led me to my solution:

- The length of `chartData` and the min idTag value are calculated based on user inputs when they click submit
- Once `min` and `length` are calculated (thus the max idTag is known), `chartData` is iteratively initialized:

`var min = 23-5*numNickel-numPenny; //numNickel & numPenny are the user inputs`

`var length = 5*(2*numNickel+1)+2*numPenny;`

`var tempTag = min;`

`for (j=0;j<length;j++) {`

`chartData[j] = {count: 0, idTag = tempTag};`

`tempTag++;`

`}`

- For reasons particular to the rules of the game, the idTag values (however many there are) are symmetrically centered around `idTag:25` (e.g. idTags = {24, 25, 26} or idTags = {20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30}. No matter the length of `chartData`, the length will always be odd and `idTag:25` will always be the `[(chartData.length-1)/2]`'th index.

Thus, if the idTags for `chartData` are `{20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30}` and if `runTrial()` gives `totalValue = 22`, then `idTag:22` will always be at index `(totalValue - min)`.

So I changed the initialization of chartData and the way the count gets increased to:

```
for (j=0; j<length; j++) {
    chartData[j] = {count: 0};  //based on what I'm doing with chartData next, I need each index to still be an object
}

for (i=0; i<timesFlipped; i++) {
    totalValue = runTrial();
    var index = totalValue - min;
    chartData[index].count++;
}
```

So thanks all for your help :)

Comment: Is that array sorted by `idTag`?

Comment: Are you free to change the structure of chartData?

Comment: @zerkms yes, the array is sorted by idTag. The array gets created sequentially, so it is sorted as it is defined.

Comment: @Danrumb yes, I can change the structure of chartData

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using client side database storage mechanisms, and let the queries do the counting for you.

This makes it more overseeable and reduces menory warnings from various virusscanners, plus you dont need to refetch data everytime.

Another approach would be to use a server side database and retrieve the values you want via json.

another aproach toprevent browser freeze is to let your loop run in a webworker so its a thread and doesnt lock the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You could create another object which points to the objects in the chartData array, like so:

```
var idToChart = {};
for (var i = 0; i < chartData.length; i++) {
    var currChart = chartData[i];
    idToChart[currChart.idTag] = currChart;
}
```

and then use

```
var chart = idToChart[totalValue];
chart.count++;
```

Accessing the object's property should be faster than looping through the array each time.

If, as @zerkms pointed out, your array is sorted by `idtag`, you wouldn't even need to create another object and could access the array directly. Ideally, `chartData` would start in the `idToChart` or sorted array format.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather maintain a intermediate hash with a "idTag" value as a key and its count as value, perform the operation with for loop, then generate charData from the intermediate hash once the for loop completes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're free to change the structure of chartData, why not just make it a hash instead of an array?

```
var chartData = {24: 0,
                 25: 0,
                 26: 0};
```

And then the loop becomes

```
for (i=0; i<timesFlipped; i++) {
    chartData[runTrial()]++;        
}
```